# Copy a file from a network share to a remote PC`s harddisk

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have this test setup:

```
# Attach a network drive to X
net use X: \\MySharename\Exchange /user:MyUser MyPassword

# copy test.txt file from share to a remote computer D (Dev)
copy X:\test.txt MyComputerNameOrIP\D:\
```

How do I syntactically correctly write the target system "MyComputerNameOrIP\D:\"

I want to copy/paste the test.txt file from Share X to another computer`s harddisk D:\

**UPDATE**

```
net use X: /delete

# Attach a network drive to X:
net use X: \\MyShare\Exchange /user:myuser mypass

# copy test.txt file from share to a remote computer D (Dev)
Copy-Item -Path X:\test.txt '\\MyComputername\D$'
```

Then I get the error: "Copy-Item : The network path was not found."

```
][Step 5/5] X: was deleted successfully.

[12:59:36][Step 5/5] 

[12:59:36][Step 5/5] The command completed successfully.

[12:59:36][Step 5/5] 

[13:00:19][Step 5/5] Copy-Item : The network path was not found.

[13:00:19][Step 5/5] At C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell1776282632632814927.ps1:7 

[13:00:19][Step 5/5] char:1

[13:00:19][Step 5/5] + Copy-Item -Path X:\test.txt '\\MyComputername\D$'

[13:00:19][Step 5/5] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

[13:00:19][Step 5/5]     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException

[13:00:19][Step 5/5]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma 

[13:00:19][Step 5/5]    nds.CopyItemCommand

[13:00:19][Step 5/5]
```

The computer name is of course faked for SO...

Comment: `\\RemoteComputerName\D$` should work as long as you have administrative access to that drive on that computer

Comment: I get this from my teamcity build: "Copy-Item : The network path was not found." When the copy command run. Which network path was not found... source or target? Do I have to use the computer IP instead of name?

Comment: I updated my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:
    `Copy-Item -Path X:\Test.txt '\\MyComputerNameOrIP\D$'`

Comment: obviously.. as mentioned by @arco444 you should have admin rights on target machine/share

Comment: Do I then not have to pass any login/password to the copy command?

Comment: You can user the -credential parameter in the command (example):
`Copy-Item -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName domain\username)`